# Create jQuery ui resizable instance using selector added to DOM by jQuery

Tags: dom, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to start a jquery ui resizable instance, but using a selector added to the DOM by jquery itself. This is a basic example of my script:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='lyr'></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Add class
$('lyr').addClass('fixed');

// Resizable
$('.fixed').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'all'
});
```

I've thought about using something along the lines of live() or bind() but I have no event to bind to. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have used the LiveQuery plugin -http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs in the past to be able to target elements added to the dom, like in your case.

Comment: Thanks, chuck it in as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the LiveQuery plugin - http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs in the past to be able to target elements added to the dom, like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If I've got this right, you want *anything* on the page which has the class "fixed" to be resizable, even if the class is added after the page has loaded? You're right that live, bind and delegate won't help here.

I can think of two possibilities, neither lovely.

First, set up a live "mouseenter" event which will make the element resizable if it wasn't before:

```
$(body).delegate(".fixed", "mouseenter", function(ev) {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    if (target.data("resizable")) return;
    target.resizable({
        aspectRatio: true,
        handles: 'all'
    });
})
```

This gets us round the problem of having no event to bind to.

Alternatively, you could monkeypatch jQuery.fn.addClass:

```
var classRe = new RegExp(c + className + \b);
._addClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
jQuery.fn.addClass = function(className) {
    if (classRe.test(classname)) {
        if (this.data("resizable")) return;
        this.resizable({
            aspectRatio: true,
            handles: 'all'
        });
    }
    jQuery.fn._addClass.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Of course this will only work if the class is added through the addClass method.

Also in your example,

```
$('lyr').addClass('fixed');
```

Should probably be:

```
$('.lyr').addClass('fixed');
```

Comment: motoxer4533's answer is better and I don't know why I didn't think of it.

Comment: Yeah this is a little clunky, but nice to know there's a non-plugin way of doing it, thanks nonetheless.